# Size Classes for Localization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

Is there anything available in Xcode that allows for changing sizes(such as labels) for different languages? All I can find are mentions of using auto-layout to account for this but there are some areas where I have to change the label size. I could make an outlet for each label, detect the locale, and then change them that way but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

The clean method is indeed auto layout, which can take the size of the text in a label into account. If that isn't good enough, then don't try looking at the locale, but look at the size of the text in the UILabel, measure it, and change things accordingly if needed.

Comment: I have titles for some view controllers that need to be translated. For those, it looks great in English but in Spanish it runs off the screen. I could shrink the size for both but it would be great if I could just shrink the size for the Spanish only. I can't really use auto layout because there just isn't enough room to make multiple lines or shift things around. The only solution is to shrink the label text size.